# How to install packages in Airflow?

Tags: pip, airflow

I deployed a dag in Airflow (on GCP) but I receive error "No module named 'scipy'".
How do I install packages in Airflow?

I've tried adding a separate DAG to run

```
def pip_install(package):
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])


def update_packages(**kwargs):
    logging.info(list(sys.modules.keys()))
    for package in PACKAGES:
        pip_install(package)
```

I've tried writing pip3 install scipy on the shell of GCP;

I've tried adding pip install scipy to the image builder.

None of these approaches had any result.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Cloud Composer on GCP, you should check https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies

Pass a `requirements.txt` file to the `gcloud` command-line tool. Format the file with each requirement specifier on a separate line.

Sample requirements.txt file:

```
scipy>=0.13.3
scikit-learn
nltk[machine_learning]
```

Pass the `requirements.txt` file to the `gcloud` command to set your installation dependencies.

```sh
gcloud composer environments update ENVIRONMENT-NAME \\
--update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt \\
--location LOCATION
```

Comment: We are using docker with Kubernetes and local executors. How can I get packages installed in Airflow without rebuilding the image