# Cannot install h2o in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, airflow, h2o

I am trying to get an Apache Airflow image to install [h2o](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/1/docs-website/h2o-docs/index.html), usually I would just need to run `pip install h2o` and it works.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701128/13337635) answer I would need to extend the image and I did so.

`airflow/Dockerfile`:

```Docker
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.2
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         build-essential h2o \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER airflow
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user h2o
```

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
---
version: "3"
x-airflow-common:
  build: ./airflow
  environment: &ref_0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ""
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "true"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "true"
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}
    AWS_ROLE_ARN: ${AWS_ROLE_ARN}
    REGION_NAME: ${REGION_NAME}
  volumes: &ref_1
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}
  depends_on: &ref_2
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD
        - pg_isready
        - -U
        - airflow
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD
        - redis-cli
        - ping
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always
  airflow-webserver:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.2}
    environment: *ref_0
    volumes: *ref_1
    user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}
    depends_on: *ref_2
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD
        - curl
        - --fail
        - http://localhost:8080/health
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
  airflow-scheduler:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.2}
    environment: *ref_0
    volumes: *ref_1
    user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}
    depends_on: *ref_2
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD-SHELL
        - airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
  airflow-worker:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.2}
    environment: *ref_0
    volumes: *ref_1
    user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}
    depends_on: *ref_2
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD-SHELL
        - >-
          celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d
          "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
  airflow-init:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.2}
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
      AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ""
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "true"
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "true"
      AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}
      REGION_NAME: ${REGION_NAME}
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
    volumes: *ref_1
    user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}
    depends_on: *ref_2
    command: version
  flower:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.2}
    environment: *ref_0
    volumes: *ref_1
    user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}
    depends_on: *ref_2
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD
        - curl
        - --fail
        - http://localhost:5555/
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

When I check the packages installed using `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> pip list`,  `h2o` cannot be found and I already have the package included in the `requirements.txt`.

Directory structure:

```
├── airflow
│   └── Dockerfile
├── dags
│   ├── 01_lasic_retraining_overview.py
│   ├── 02_lasic_retraining_sagemaker_autopilot.py
│   ├── 03_lasic_retraining_h20_automl.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── common
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── helper.py
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── requirements.txt
```

Error confirmation inside of airflow:

[image]

#### EDIT:

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67890645/13337635) as well but still the same issue.

Comment: Please use language tag.

Comment: Please verify that the Dockerfile inside of the container reflects the changes that you made. I suspect that you might've changed the Dockerfile outside without recreating the image.

Comment: @AndrewWei I ran `docker-compose down -v && docker-compose up -d --build` that should reset eveything once I made changes correct?

Comment: When it rebuilds, do you see the step that runs the `pip install`? I think it'd only build the image being used, not necessarily run all the steps.

Comment: I connected into the container and ran `pip install h2o` and it installed which shows that its failing at the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Try doing `cat` on the `Dockerfile` in the container as a sanity-check that the Dockerfile actually tries to install it.

Comment: But the `Dockerfile` doesn't get uploaded to the container, so how would I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236307/discussion-between-andrew-wei-and-yudhiesh).

Answer (score 1):

The `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> pip list` is not enough to check if package is installed in the image. Airflow image uses custom entrypoint which you need to use to enter the image to get into the same environment, airflow containers are running in. This is mainly to make it open-shift compatible and allows to run it via different users - not only airflow, but also root and any other users you want.

You can see details about the entrypoint here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html

I built the image using your dockerfile:

```
docker build . --tag my-image
```

And it worked just fine. When I enter the image using `bash` command (as described in the "entrypoint" documentation, I got h2o properly installed:

```
docker run -it my-image bash
airflow@d319ba82f3b4:/opt/airflow$ pip freeze | grep h2o
h2o==3.32.1.6
```

The way you can actually check if the image has the right dependencies installed, is to `exec` into the running container via `/entrypoint`. I did it as well on a running container and it looks good:

```
exec -it d319ba82f3b4 /entrypoint bash
airflow@d319ba82f3b4:/opt/airflow$ pip freeze | grep h2o
h2o==3.32.1.6
airflow@d319ba82f3b4:/opt/airflow$
```

Also this works quite fine:

```
docker exec -it d319ba82f3b4 /entrypoint bash -c 'pip list | grep h2o'
h2o                                      3.32.1.6
```

Likely - for some reason, still old not rebuilt image is used. Did you run `docker-compose up` with `--build` flag? You can also run `docker-compose build` to make sure that your images are rebuilt when you use `build` directive in docker-compose.

There is one comment to your image though.

Your image is highly un-optimized. Because you've added `build-essentials` to the image, your image is about 200 MB (at least) bigger than it could be if you go "customization" route. Going that route is a bit more complex (requires Airflow sources) but it's well worth it. See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#customizing-the-image  there are some examples where going `customization` route saves ~25% of image  size.